# GDB "cannot find bounds of current function" when stepping into trampoline function at a special address

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, riscv, xv6

When I try to debug XV6 (an OS), I find GDB can't reach the assembly code.
I want to find out how to trace the executing path in the assembly code.

The file `kernel/trap.c` refers to the assembly code `kernel/trampoline.S` by the `extern` keyword, so that the identifiers `trampoline`, `uservec` and the `userrer` are actually the labels in the assembly code `kernel/trampoline.S`:

```c
extern char trampoline[], uservec[], userret[];
```

```
    #
        # code to switch between user and kernel space.
        #
        # this code is mapped at the same virtual address
        # (TRAMPOLINE) in user and kernel space so that
        # it continues to work when it switches page tables.
    #
    # kernel.ld causes this to be aligned
        # to a page boundary.
        #
    .section trampsec
.globl trampoline
trampoline:
.align 4
.globl uservec
uservec:    
    #
        # trap.c sets stvec to point here, so
        # traps from user space start here,
        # in supervisor mode, but with a
        # user page table.
        #
        # sscratch points to where the process's p->trapframe is
        # mapped into user space, at TRAPFRAME.
        #
        
    # swap a0 and sscratch
        # so that a0 is TRAPFRAME
        csrrw a0, sscratch, a0

        # save the user registers in TRAPFRAME
        sd ra, 40(a0)
        sd sp, 48(a0)
        sd gp, 56(a0)
        sd tp, 64(a0)
        sd t0, 72(a0)
        sd t1, 80(a0)
        sd t2, 88(a0)
        sd s0, 96(a0)
        sd s1, 104(a0)
        sd a1, 120(a0)
        sd a2, 128(a0)
        sd a3, 136(a0)
        sd a4, 144(a0)
        sd a5, 152(a0)
        sd a6, 160(a0)
        sd a7, 168(a0)
        sd s2, 176(a0)
        sd s3, 184(a0)
        sd s4, 192(a0)
        sd s5, 200(a0)
        sd s6, 208(a0)
        sd s7, 216(a0)
        sd s8, 224(a0)
        sd s9, 232(a0)
        sd s10, 240(a0)
        sd s11, 248(a0)
        sd t3, 256(a0)
        sd t4, 264(a0)
        sd t5, 272(a0)
        sd t6, 280(a0)

    # save the user a0 in p->trapframe->a0
        csrr t0, sscratch
        sd t0, 112(a0)

        # restore kernel stack pointer from p->trapframe->kernel_sp
        ld sp, 8(a0)

        # make tp hold the current hartid, from p->trapframe->kernel_hartid
        ld tp, 32(a0)

        # load the address of usertrap(), p->trapframe->kernel_trap
        ld t0, 16(a0)

        # restore kernel page table from p->trapframe->kernel_satp
        ld t1, 0(a0)
        csrw satp, t1
        sfence.vma zero, zero

        # a0 is no longer valid, since the kernel page
        # table does not specially map p->tf.

        # jump to usertrap(), which does not return
        jr t0

.globl userret
userret:
        # userret(TRAPFRAME, pagetable)
        # switch from kernel to user.
        # usertrapret() calls here.
        # a0: TRAPFRAME, in user page table.
        # a1: user page table, for satp.

        # switch to the user page table.
        csrw satp, a1
        sfence.vma zero, zero

        # put the saved user a0 in sscratch, so we
        # can swap it with our a0 (TRAPFRAME) in the last step.
        ld t0, 112(a0)
        csrw sscratch, t0

        # restore all but a0 from TRAPFRAME
        ld ra, 40(a0)
        ld sp, 48(a0)
        ld gp, 56(a0)
        ld tp, 64(a0)
        ld t0, 72(a0)
        ld t1, 80(a0)
        ld t2, 88(a0)
        ld s0, 96(a0)
        ld s1, 104(a0)
        ld a1, 120(a0)
        ld a2, 128(a0)
        ld a3, 136(a0)
        ld a4, 144(a0)
        ld a5, 152(a0)
        ld a6, 160(a0)
        ld a7, 168(a0)
        ld s2, 176(a0)
        ld s3, 184(a0)
        ld s4, 192(a0)
        ld s5, 200(a0)
        ld s6, 208(a0)
        ld s7, 216(a0)
        ld s8, 224(a0)
        ld s9, 232(a0)
        ld s10, 240(a0)
        ld s11, 248(a0)
        ld t3, 256(a0)
        ld t4, 264(a0)
        ld t5, 272(a0)
        ld t6, 280(a0)

    # restore user a0, and save TRAPFRAME in sscratch
        csrrw a0, sscratch, a0
        
        # return to user mode and user pc.
        # usertrapret() set up sstatus and sepc.
        sret
```

And the function `usertrapret()` use the function pointer to skip to the assembly code in the `kernel/trampoline.S`. The skipping statement is in the end of the function `usertrapret()`.

```c
//
// return to user space
//
void usertrapret(void) {
  struct proc *p = myproc();

  // we're about to switch the destination of traps from
  // kerneltrap() to usertrap(), so turn off interrupts until
  // we're back in user space, where usertrap() is correct.
  intr_off();

  // send syscalls, interrupts, and exceptions to trampoline.S
  w_stvec(TRAMPOLINE + (uservec - trampoline));

  // set up trapframe values that uservec will need when
  // the process next re-enters the kernel.
  p->trapframe->kernel_satp = r_satp();         // kernel page table
  p->trapframe->kernel_sp = p->kstack + PGSIZE; // process's kernel stack
  p->trapframe->kernel_trap = (uint64)usertrap;
  p->trapframe->kernel_hartid = r_tp(); // hartid for cpuid()

  // set up the registers that trampoline.S's sret will use
  // to get to user space.

  // set S Previous Privilege mode to User.
  unsigned long x = r_sstatus();
  x &= ~SSTATUS_SPP; // clear SPP to 0 for user mode
  x |= SSTATUS_SPIE; // enable interrupts in user mode
  w_sstatus(x);

  // set S Exception Program Counter to the saved user pc.
  w_sepc(p->trapframe->epc);

  // tell trampoline.S the user page table to switch to.
  uint64 satp = MAKE_SATP(p->pagetable);

  // jump to trampoline.S at the top of memory, which
  // switches to the user page table, restores user registers,
  // and switches to user mode with sret.
  uint64 fn = TRAMPOLINE + (userret - trampoline);
  ((void (*)(uint64, uint64))fn)(TRAPFRAME, satp);
}
```

When I use GDB command `stepi` to trace the executing path, and when I encouter the statement, the GDB can't go on tracing the assembly, and the GDB will report "Cannot find bounds of current function", so I can't keep on tracing the detailed execution of the assembly code.

```c
((void (*)(uint64, uint64))fn)(TRAPFRAME, satp);
```

[image: the detailed image is here]

Comment: I don't know xv6 but on other platforms this just means it can't figure out where the function starts. It wants to disassemble from the beginning of the function. You have to use more annoying commands to tell it where to start and stop disassembling. Try something like `disassemble $eip-100, $eip+10`

Comment: The `Cannot find bounds of current function` message only appears twice in the GDB source, once for the `step` command, and once for `reverse-finish`.  I suspect you're using `step` not `stepi`.  Try actually using `stepi` and see if that works better.

Comment: As GDB said, `Cannot find bounds of current fuctions` shows that gdb found PC is not in a vaild address range of a fuction. As well as `.text` segment is continuous and no exceptions happened but it works find while running, it should be that no `debug symbols` generated for fuctions in Assembly, please show more build system infomation in addition to the question.